# EditableGeoJsonLayer gets TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Tags: javascript, typescript, mapbox, deck.gl

I am trying to use Editable geojsonlayer from nebula.gl, as per documentation and I am getting numerous typescript error for this library. First type of error can be found replicated and solved in their repository issues: https://github.com/uber/nebula.gl/issues/568

And after hours of hunting and finding the solution above, I am able to draw a polygon using DrawPolygoneMode, but when I close the polygon, I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.
```

I am not able to post the whole error here, but it has to do with the library files where the type isnt defined properly hence so many incompatibility errors for typescript, such as:

```
ImmutableFeatureCollection.addFeatures
src/lib/immutable-feature-collection.ts:184

181 | addFeatures(features: Feature[]): ImmutableFeatureCollection {
182 |   const updatedFeatureCollection = {
183 |     ...this.featureCollection,
184 |     features: [...this.featureCollection.features, ...features],
    | ^  185 |   };
186 | 
187 |   return new ImmutableFeatureCollection(updatedFeatureCollection);
```

Below is my code where I am trying to use EditableGeoJsonLayer. You will notice that I have defined it as  `const editLayer = new (EditableGeoJsonLayer as any)({` or else it wasn't recognizing it as a function with more than 1 arguments.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DeckGL from '@deck.gl/react';
import { EditableGeoJsonLayer } from '@nebula.gl/layers';
import {DrawPolygonMode } from 'nebula.gl';
import {StaticMap} from 'react-map-gl';


function MapBox(props) {
// Viewport settings
const [INITIAL_VIEW_STATE, setViewport] = useState({
    longitude: 88.49175358524279,
    latitude: 22.571194159512256,
    zoom: 13,
    pitch: 0,
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 22,
    bearing: 0
});
const [mapMode, setMapMode] = useState("mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v8")
const myFeatureCollection:any = {
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: [
        
    ],
  };

const selectedFeatureIndexes = [];
const [featureState, setFeatureState] = useState({
    data: myFeatureCollection,
})

const editableLayer = new (EditableGeoJsonLayer as any)({
    id: 'geojson',
    data: featureState.data,
    mode: DrawPolygonMode,
    selectedFeatureIndexes,
    onEdit: (updatedData:any) => {
        setFeatureState({ data: updatedData });
    },
});

return(
    <>
        <DeckGL
            initialViewState={INITIAL_VIEW_STATE}
            controller={true}
            layers={[editableLayer]} 
            style={{height: "100vh", width: "100%"}}
        >
            <StaticMap mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN} mapStyle={mapMode}/>
        </DeckGL>
    </>
       
     
   );
  }

  export default MapBox;
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am new to this library and the documentation seems to unclear at times on what library to use for particular function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. This worked for me:

```
new (EditableGeoJsonLayer as any)({
         id: 'geojson',
         data: featureState.data,
         mode: DrawPolygonMode,
         selectedFeatureIndexes,
         onEdit: ({updatedData}):any => {
             setFeatureState({ 
                 data: updatedData 
             });
             console.log("GeoJson Updated!!");
             console.log(featureState.data);
         },
         pickable: true,
         pickingRadius: 15,
    })
```

I changed if from `(updatedData:any)` to `({updatedData}):any` and that did the job.